# SSH connexion over the internet while VPN is on

Tags: ssh, routing, vpn, internet

I opened the port 22 from my router configuration and I installed a dynamic DNS in order to connect to my machine over the internet.

The problem is, I often use this same machine to connect to a VPN (HMA VPN), and once this VPN is active, I can no longer connect to this machine over the internet because, naturally, my public IP is no longer the public IP of my router, but instead, the one of the VPN server.
I suppose that my port forwarding is not effective anymore in this situation.

Can someone explain me how to solve this problem please?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem using "split tunneling".  Basically, some traffic through the VPN and some not.

From a quick search, HMA may not offer that.  from:https://vpn-services.bestreviews.net/vpn-comparison-hidemyass-vs-purevpn/ :

> An additional feature offered by PureVPN is Split Tunneling, where you
>   have the option to use only certain applications through the VPN,
>   while sending other information through your local LAN or WAN. This
>   gets rid of the cumbersome need to disconnect and reconnect to the
>   server if you want to access a corporate network or have some programs
>   that do not work well with a VPN.

Our corporate VPN is split tunnel.  This way, corporate traffic goes through the VPN, but he bandwidth for the youtube videos people are watching will not.

In your case, If you use PureVPN, you can set it up so that only one application goes through the VPN, or all but one application goes through the vpn.

How to use PureVPN to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eII1xUeO18

A better explanation of split tunneling:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFGAXSUSsVg